# SQL syntax for "if exists"

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Why I'm getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;  
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = '1')' at line 1
```

My SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = '1')
```

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Is that the whole query?  What's the IF statement doing?  Shouldn't there be a statement block after it?

Comment: Yeah, if that's the whole query - it doesn't work because it's not a complete statement. If it isn't, we need the rest to judge what is going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IF EXISTS` only works in a stored procedure. Outside of a stored procedure, `IF()` is a function which takes 3 arguments. Proper usage would be

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = `1`), 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Declare @ID Integer
Select @ID=id From mytable where id=1
IF @ID is not null    OR  IF @ID > 0
Begin
....
End
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter. `WHERE id = '1'` will work fine even if `id` is an integer.

Comment: I agree with Mark Byers - MySQL does implicit data type conversion between INT and string data types.

Answer (score 0):

Not on a MySQL machine right now but it looks like its because the statement is incomplete, you need to tell it what to do if the id exists.

IF EXISTS(...) *do something*

Answer (score 0):

`IF EXISTS` doesn't make any sense in MySQL.
See [subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) in the MySQL documentation on usage.

Basically, you need to use it in a statement, and not just like a logical block

Comment: IF EXISTS is often used in SQL Server, because it's less verbose than `IF(SELECT COUNT()...) > 0` etc.