# UPDATE if exists else INSERT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to implement a SQL query to "UPDATE if exists else INSERT"

My table(`Allowance`) is as below:

```
EmployeeID int(8) PK
Year year(4) PK
Month int(2) PK
OverTime decimal(10,2)
Medical decimal(10,2)
Lunch decimal(10,2)
Bonus decimal(10,2)
Allowance decimal(10,2)
```

Below is the SQL query I tried:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Allowance WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = 2014 and Month = 4)
    UPDATE Allowance
    SET OverTime = 10.00, Medical = 10.00, Lunch = 10.45, Bonus =10.10, Allowance = 40.55
    WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = 2014 and Month = 4
ELSE
    INSERT into Allowance values (10000001,2014,4,10.00,10.00,10.45,10.10,40.55)
```

I keep getting this error message:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Allowance WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = 2014 an' at line 1 "

Can somebody please help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql syntax, if exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241563/sql-syntax-if-exist)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54335/insert-update-to-merge-data-when-empty-data-is-an-empty-string does this helps?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The below query will fulfill your requirement.

```
INSERT INTO `ALLOWANCE` (`EmployeeID`, `Year`, `Month`, `OverTime`,`Medical`,
`Lunch`, `Bonus`, `Allowance`) values (10000001, 2014, 4, 10.00, 10.00,
10.45, 10.10, 40.55) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `EmployeeID` = 10000001
```

Comment: Yes, this one works :) Thank you very much Gunaseelan

Comment: @Gunaseelan when it is updated it is creating a new id if have auto increment id, how to prevent this?

Comment: @Looper Is the column your primary key which is auto-incremented?

Comment: @Gunaseelan yes ID is the primary key and I have unique key also

Answer (score 7):

Further to Gunaseelan's answer *(answering questions I had myself, that I needed to look up)*:

```
INSERT INTO `ALLOWANCE` (`EmployeeID`, `Year`, `Month`, `OverTime`,`Medical`,
`Lunch`, `Bonus`, `Allowance`) values (10000001, 2014, 4, 10.00, 10.00,
10.45, 10.10, 40.55) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `OverTime`=10.00, `Medical`=10.00, `Lunch`=10.45, `Bonus`=10.10, `Allowance`=40.55;
```

1. Don't forget the trailing semicolon *(like I did)*;
2. WHERE is not required - it knows which record is the duplicate
3. Also no need to mention the tablename again - that was provided in first half

Here is a page that explains the syntax in more detail:

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-insert--on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 3):

With this procedure you can check if exist or not and then update/insert as you want

```
 DELIMITER $$;   
 CREATE PROCEDURE example()

BEGIN
DECLARE vexist int;

  SELECT count(*) into vexist FROM Allowance --count because i will
  WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = 2014 and Month = 4;  --this will check if exist or not

    IF (vexist >= 1) then  --if exist then update
    UPDATE Allowance
        SET OverTime = 10.00, Medical = 10.00, Lunch = 10.45, Bonus =10.10, Allowance = 40.55
        WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = 2014 and Month = 4;
    ELSE
      INSERT into Allowance values (10000001,2014,4,10.00,10.00,10.45,10.10,40.55);
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You have to call the procedure now:

```
call example();
```

Note: This will solve you solution as for now, but it's not the best idea since `procedures` are intended to get used in the future aswell, so i'll give you an improved version where in the future you will be able to update/insert by just invoking the procedure and wrinting your inserts values.

```
DELIMITER $$;   
     CREATE PROCEDURE example(
IN
vempid int(8),
vyear year(4), 
vmonth int(2),
vovertime float(10,2),
vmedical float(10,2),
vlunch float(10,2),
vbonus float(10,2),
vallowance float(10,2))

    BEGIN
    DECLARE vexist int;

      SELECT count(*) into vexist FROM Allowance --count because i will
      WHERE EmployeeID =vemp and Year = vyear and Month = vmonth;  --this will check if exist or not

        IF (vexist >= 1) then  --if exist then update
        UPDATE Allowance
            SET OverTime = vovertime, Medical = vmedical, Lunch = vlunch, Bonus = vbonus, Allowance = vallowabce
            WHERE EmployeeID =10000001 and Year = vyear and Month = vmonth;
        ELSE
          INSERT INTO `ALLOWANCE` (`EmployeeID`, `Year`, `Month`, `OverTime`,`Medical`,`Lunch`, `Bonus`, `Allowance`) values (vempid,vyear,vmonth,vovertime,vmedical,vlunch,vbonus,vallowance);
    END IF;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

And invoking (with the correct parameters order):

```
call example2(10000001,2014,4,10.00,10.00,10.45,10.10,40.5);
```

Comment: I recently noticed you just had an answer, anyway this might help you in the future for more incoming checks(updates/inserts) and writing less than a whole insert.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write custom SQL for this. MySQL already has `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which does exactly same thing.

If you specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.

Please read [URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT IF (EXISTS())` instead of `IF EXISTS()`

[Usage of MySQL's "IF EXISTS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists)

Comment: if it is answer then it should be written as answer only not as comment@PankajK

Comment: @PankajK, if one line answers the question I see no problem here. Do you expect to add `The Tragical Historie of Hamlet, Prince of Denmarke` story to the answer?