# Update Database if data exists else Insert in MySQL in a single step

Tags: mysql

For my Application, I need to check whether data exists for some column. If exists, add a value 10 to the existing value else insert a new entry

I'm trying something like this

```
UPDATE reporting set column_name1 = column_name1 + 10 WHERE column_name2 = "201";
IF ROW_COUNT()=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO reporting (column_name1,column_name2) VALUES (15,201);
END IF
```

In my Table column_name2 is not a primary Key and I have disabled Safe checks.Due to this reason, I cannot use DUPLICATE KEY constraint.For this Query, I'm getting Syntax Error:

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 THEN     INSERT INTO reporting (identifier,_9_2017) ' at line 1`

The syntax of If statement is similar to the one in MySQL Documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html. There are few Questions related to this in this portal but I couldn't find the right answer ([UPDATE if exists else INSERT in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569666/update-if-exists-else-insert-in-sql)). Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your situation, but MySQL has a `REPLACE INTO` clause that updates if exists, and inserts if not. You can read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ROW_COUNT()` like this

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Comment: Even after using ROW_COUNT(), Error still persists in IF Statement